# How to extract CRL location from x509 certificate using OpenSSL utility

Tags: openssl, certificate-authority, crl

I need to extract the crl location from a certificate authority so I can use that in verifying certificates. Is this possible using the `openssl` utility other than using the `-text` option and attempting to parse the output (which seems prone to vulnerabilities)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`openssl x509` has some switches to control the formatting of the output and it's possible to not display some fields, but getting *just* the CRL location does not seem to be possible.

It seems you're bound to parse the output.

Comment: There is not only `x509` in `openssl` toolkit.

Answer (score 3):

Still kind of parsing, but at least more precise than with `x509`.
It needs to be improved to better take into account lists, the `cut -b21-` is really a shortcut in case of simple 1 element list.

```
openssl asn1parse -in whatever.crt | grep -A 1 'X509v3 CRL Distribution Points' | tail -1 | cut -d: -f 4 | cut -b21- | perl -ne 's/(..)/print chr(hex($1))/ge; END {print "\n"}'
http://cdp.rapidssl.com/RapidSSLTLSRSACAG1.crl
```

compared to:

```
openssl x509 -text -in whatever.crt |grep -A4 'CRL Distribution Points'
        X509v3 CRL Distribution Points:

            Full Name:
              URI:http://cdp.rapidssl.com/RapidSSLTLSRSACAG1.crl
```

Or using any kind of programming language you could have something close, depending on how much the underlying libraries decode things for you:

```
php -r '$cert = file_get_contents("whatever.crt"); $ssl = openssl_x509_parse($cert); print_r($ssl["extensions"]["crlDistributionPoints"]);'

Full Name:
  URI:http://cdp.rapidssl.com/RapidSSLTLSRSACAG1.crl
```